# Passing a filename as an argument in ruby

Tags: ruby, string, methods, parameters

```
def file_to_array(filename)
  my_text = []
  File.open(filename, "r").each do |line|
    my_text << line
  end
my_text
end
```

Hello! My method is supposed to receive a filename when called, open the file and move each line to an array. However, it raises `undefined local variable` when called and I'm assuming it has something to do with the filename[DOT]ext ?!
My call happens in a method below

```
def clean_array
  cleaned = file_to_array(text.txt).map do |element|
    element.gsub(/\b['s\!\.\\n]*/m, "")
  end
  cleaned.map! do |el|
    el.split(" ")
    end
  return cleaned.flatten!
  #p cleaned
end
```

Comment: As an aside, in this case you can use the method [IO::read](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/IO.html#method-c-read) to "gulp" the file into an array: `def file_to_array(filename); IO.read(filename); end`. Often you will see `File.read(filename)` instead of `IO.read(filename)`. That's OK because `File` is a subclass of `IO` and therefore inherits the latter's methods. In situations where memory considerations dictate that you need to read a file line-by-line, [IO::foreach](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/IO.html#method-c-foreach) is often the go-to method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file name should be a string, and as such, passed in quotes:

```
file_to_array("text.txt")
# OR
file_to_array('text.txt')
```